# Редирект на домен при выборе города

Tags: javascript, html, opencart

Есть такая задача: три домена, клоны, разница в базе товаров, витрины разные (особенность обмена с 1С). Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при первом входе на любой из доменов, высвечивалось всплывающее окно со списком городов, и при выборе города, согласно справочнику, который создаётся вручную, происходил редирект на определённый домен. Город автоматический определять не надо, ибо с учётом специфики работы складов, разные города в одной области или крае могут обслуживать разные склады. Главное ещё, чтобы это всплывающее окно нельзя было закрыть не выбрав город.

Answer (score 0):

Что вам необходимо:

1. Открываем контроллер шапки и реализуем там проверку на наличие у пользователя куки с регионом.
2. Если кука есть молча переадресуем на нужный домен. Если нет, то добавляем в шапку блок с выбором региона.
3. Сам блок с помощью css делаем фиксированный, на весь сайт, без возможности его закрытия. В блоке соответственно выводим список ваших доменов/регионов.
4. На js делаем выбор домена: после того, как он был выбран, записываем в куку и переадресуем.